# Format of .dex files for Android 2.1 (Eclair), i.e. API level 7

Tags: android, dalvik, dex

I'm [writing an assembler](https://github.com/akavel/dali) for Android/Dalvik .dex files. The [official Android docs](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format.html) seem to only describe the **newest version of the .dex format** (apparently `038` as of May 2019), with a few short notes describing differences **back to version `035`**. A [quick glimpse into Android sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/6f3916321e14235a0bceea92a90460215f4c1b73/dx/src/com/android/dex/DexFormat.java#61) seems to suggest, that version `035` of the format corresponds to Android **API level 13**, meaning [Android 3.2.x](https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers) (Honeycomb). I own a [device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nook_Simple_Touch) with Android 2.1 (Eclair), which [apparently](https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers) means **API level 7**. I would like to be able to learn how to emit correct .dex and .apk files for that device, to hopefully add support for those to my assembler.

**Where can I find information that could help me emit correct .dex files for Android 2.1 (Eclair), i.e. API level 7?** I don't even know what's the .dex format version string for that API level!

For "bonus points", I would really love to find some good reference explaining the differences in .dex format between all API levels (at least back to API level 7). I would be also interested if there are any substantial differences in the format of the binary .xml and resource files (as emitted by the `aapt` tool) between Android API levels. I assume that there's a high chance the .apk format itself, as well as the signing algorithm, hopefully didn't change *at all*, given that it's the same format used to sign Java .jar files (i.e. a regular .zip with a few simple special files in the `META-INF/` subdirectory). But the .dex format spec (including bytecodes) is probably the most important part, or at least a good starting point.

Comment: Aside for the educational purposes it would be pure waste of time. See OS version distribution chart https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards

Comment: The binary resource/xml formats are not documented nor well-specified. You pretty much have to read through the aapt and/or android-framework code to figure out the format. There have been changes over time, although I think mostly superficial stuff - the structure hasn't significantly changed.

Comment: See here for info on the different apk signing schemes: https://source.android.com/security/apksigning

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Please note I explicitly wrote I actually own (and happily use!) a 2.1 (API lvl 7) device, so it would be potentially at least of some personal use too! :)

Comment: I might have missed that. Still - your time, not mine :) I just wanted to point out that while it may be fun doing that, no one would likely complain for lack of support for medieval devices :)

Comment: @Marcin The distribution chart only covers devices with Google Play Store, however in the embedded market Android 2.1 AFAIK is still in use, e.g. as Android based car head unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format has some quick blurbs on the differences between the versions.

```
Note: Support for version 037 of the format was added in the Android 7.0 
release. Prior to version 037 most versions of Android have used version 035 of 
the format. The only difference between versions 035 and 037 is the addition of 
default methods and the adjustment of the invoke.
```

---

```
Note: Support for version 038 of the format was added in the Android 8.0 
release. Version 038 added new bytecodes (invoke-polymorphic and invoke- 
custom) and data for method handles.
```

Although, note that the newest version is 039, which doesn't seem to be mentioned in the doc. iirc, 039 added the `invoke-custom/range`, `const-method-handle` and `const-method-type` instructions.

Other sources of information include looking at the changelog of those documents:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/docs/source.android.com/+log/refs/heads/master/en/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format.html
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/docs/source.android.com/+log/refs/heads/master/en/devices/tech/dalvik/dalvik-bytecode.html

And prior to that, before the files were moved:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/docs/source.android.com/+log/a3b748b40bab557fb47fe5a48a5bfb642837fb05/src/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format.jd
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/docs/source.android.com/+log/a3b748b40bab557fb47fe5a48a5bfb642837fb05/src/devices/tech/dalvik/dalvik-bytecode.jd

Also, you should be able to glean some info from the smali source. It has the [min/max api levels](https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali/blob/master/dexlib2/src/main/java/org/jf/dexlib2/Opcode.java), where applicable, for every instruction.

For the instructions with the min/max set as an art version, you can use [this mapping](https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali/blob/2f29256/dexlib2/src/main/java/org/jf/dexlib2/VersionMap.java#L65) to map back to an api level.

Comment: I was kinda hoping you might answer some day, didn't expect so fast, thanks! :D That said, even the .jd files seem to start with Gingerbread (API lvl 10) and already mention .dex format `035`. But at least now I know some file names, so I can try digging for some previous renames. As to the blurbs describing format `035` in current docs, I already saw them, as I mention in the question. Finally, the `smali` sources, they seem to reject (?) pre-035 .dex and API lvl <19 with `NO_VERSION`, right? So, probably not too useful for my API lvl 7 needs anyway? :(

Comment: format 035 was what the first version of android shipped with

Comment: Oh. I didn't expect that. I downloaded some .apk back from my 2.1 device, that I know worked on it, then unzipped it, and indeed, the classes.dex in there has the `035` format marker. Awesome, thanks, that's what I didn't know!